# Problems involving $L^1$, $L^2$ Spaces and Adjoint Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm not getting two questions.
Can you help me please.

"Consider the sets $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $V = L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

a) Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\left(1+x^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but is square integrable.

b) Show that V is vectorial subspace.

c) Define $\mathcal{F}: V \to V$ by 
$$
\mathcal{F}(f)(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\theta x}\;dx
$$
Find $\mathcal{F}^*$.

Coments: $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ are spaces of integrable functions with standard norm $||f||_p = \left(\int|f(x)|^p\;dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $ and $\mathcal{F}^*$ denote is Adjoint Operator.

I did the first item follows:
$f(x) = f(-x)$ for any $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$. Then, 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx $
$= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx $
$= \lim_{t \to +\infty} \int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx $
$=\ln |x + \sqrt{x^2+1}| \Big|_0^t $
$= +\infty.
$
Therefore does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

But I can not prove the second part of the first item and the others.
Hints, tips, solutions, will help me a lot.
Thank you.

Comment: a) compare with $|x|^{-1}$  for the square compare with $x^{-2}$. b) V is a subspace as an intersection of vectorial subspaces. c) Isn't it just $\mathcal{F^*}=\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Are you sure about $\mathcal{F}(f) \in V$? If $f = \mathbf{1}_{[0,4]}$, then $\mathcal{F}(f)(1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} (\sin(4) + i + i \cos(4) )$. So either $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ contains functions to $\mathbb{C}$, which makes it, in my opinion, weird that you state in a) a function which goes to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AlexFish What I did in the first item it's wrong?
b) and c) I believe I understand with your help.

Comment: @Hetebrij I don't understand. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure you did the integration correctly but maybe I'm just missing something and in that case it would be fine. It's easier to use knowledge of well known integrals and compare. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=C>0$ then $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ and $\int_a^\infty g(x)dx$ converge and diverge together, assuming there are no more "problematic" points. In your case $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(1+x^2)^{-1/2}}{x^{-1}}=1$ and we know $\int_1^\infty x^{-1}$ diverges thus $\int_1^\infty (1+x^2)^{-1/2}$ diverges which implies $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+x^2)^{-1/2}$ diverges.

Comment: For the square you don't have problems at $0$ since this is covered by the $+1$ so you only have to check at $\infty$. We all know $\int_1^\infty x^{-2}$ converges and $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(1+x^2)^{-1}}{x^{-2}}=1$.

Comment: @AlexFish Thanks!